# Issue Listing multiple SVN repositories from client

Tags: apache, svn, repository

I've already setup Apache to manage svn requests. 
Basically the structure of the svn related directory is this:

/Repository 
-----OneRepo
-----TheOtherRepo

Repository is a "normal" directory, while OneRepo and TheOtherRepo are svn repositories.

I've used **SVNParentPath** and **SVNListParentPath** directives and if I go to  localhost/Repository/ (with my browser) I can see all my repositories.

Now, if I try to access a single repository (for example: OneRepo) from a client (in my case Cornerstone but Versions is the same) everything works fine.

The problem is that I would like to access the repository listing from the client so that I have a big "folder" with all my projects in it. Does it make sense?

So, instead of writing http://192.168.x.x/Repository/OneRepo in my client (and it works) I would like to write http://192.168.x.x/Repository/ and view a listing of project and so checkout whatever project I would like to.
Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works only in a http browser. So your standard SVN Client (commandline , TortoiseSVN, etc.) **can not** list your repositories

Comment: Thanks Peter. So, I guess that to achieve that I should use svnserve daemon instead. Right?

Comment: No, it is simply not possible to get a list of all repositories. "svn ls" is for reading _inside_ a repository, bot a parent dir..